# Insert/Update on single button

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have `modalpopup` with `textboxes` in it.
Before the user gets to the `modal popup`, he either clicks ADD or EDIT.
If he clicks ADD, all the `textboxes` are empty and he gets to add a new address.
If he clicks EDIT, the `textboxes` already contain his address and he gets to edit his address.
 Now I have a single SAVE button on which I have to decide whether the data in the textboxes needs to be `INSERTED (ADDED)` or `UPDATED (EDITED)`.
 How do I achieve this?
 I mean how do I find out if the user has clicked on ADD or EDIT??

Comment: Google is still free.

Comment: I reached SO through google..! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745761/how-to-put-and-use-two-flagsinsert-and-update-flags-on-a-single-button-to-perf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keep the action in the viestate and check what value it is.

If user click edit then on editclick

```
ViewStat["Action"]="Edit";
```

On save button check for the view state value

```
if(ViewStat["Action"]!=null)
{
   if(ViewStat["Action"].ToString()=="Edit")
   {
     //update statement
   }
   else
   {
       //insert statement
   }
}
```

Also you can also set it to empty or null on cancel click

```
ViewState["Action"]=null;
```

Comment: what is "Edit" here? what do I put in place of Edit?

Comment: it is nothing but a value to decide what action to do. You can put anything which you like.

Comment: what are you doing to open a model popup? using jQuery? Is there any postback after add or edit button clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Take an `hidden field` in your page. On add button click set its value to `"0"` and on edit button click set value to the id of the record that has to be updated. You can check value of your hidden field on server side to decide what to do.