# how to put and use two flags(insert and update flags) on a single button to perform two operations in asp.net with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to put two flags(insert and update flags) on a single button to perform two operations in asp.net with C#.

**Please help me out**

```
if (strflag.ToUpper() == "Insert")
{
    du.ExecQry("insert into Crop_Master(Crop_Name,Created_On,Created_By,Created_By_Ip)values('" + TextBox1.Text + "',GETDATE(),'" + ViewState["user"] + "','" + ViewState["ip"] + "')");
    Label2.Text = "Submitted";
    Label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
}
else if(strflag.ToUpper()=="Update")
{
    du.ExecQry("Update Crop_Master set Crop_Name= '"+TextBox1.Text+"' where Crop_Name='@Crop_Name' ");
}
```

Comment: What was the issue in that code? what you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to perform two operations using flags with a single button but don't know how to use it

Comment: can you share the design? how the box & buttons are present? or explain it. is it possible to add a checkbox in that

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701927/insert-update-on-single-button

Comment: @stuartd but he is not having multiple buttons, we have wait for Aman to clearly explain about the design..

Comment: I have one gridview ,one textbox and one button.Now i want to select value in gridview and that value should be displayed on textbox.Now from this textbox i can edit and then insert the value into table when i click the button

Answer (score 1):

```
var record = du.SelectQuery("select * from where Crop_Master Crop_Name='@Crop_Name");
if(record.Count > 0) {
    du.ExecQry("Update Crop_Master set Crop_Name= '"+TextBox1.Text+"' where Crop_Name='@Crop_Name' ");
} else {
    du.ExecQry("insert into Crop_Master(Crop_Name,Created_On,Created_By,Created_By_Ip)values('" + TextBox1.Text + "',GETDATE(),'" + ViewState["user"] + "','" + ViewState["ip"] + "')");
}
Label2.Text = "Submitted";
Label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
```

I Just help you out with task, but don't like about your coding and db design style...

be more professional

Comment: @stuartd i just guided to him for a better design... sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can add new Class library project to your solution and

**Extend Button**

Add below reference

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls
```

Create an `enum`

```
public enum StateOfInsertion
{
    Update,Insert
}

public MyButton : Button
{
     public StateOfInsertion State { get; set; }
}
```

And use this `Control` like other and drag it to design mode from `Toolbox`